# How can I "hot reload" my code using Pulumi?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pulumi

I have been using `aws.lambda.Function` to deploy to either AWS or my [localstack](https://localstack.cloud/) setup and I was hoping I could have a fast way to iterate over local changes, but I couldn't find a way to do so.

I noticed that `aws.lambda.Function` zips the code (`pulumi.asset.AssetArchive`), which means that enabling hot swapping in localstack won't make any difference unless we have a way to make Pulumi repack the content of the lambda on demand.

- I have tried using `pulumi watch`, but with no success. It seems that only the pulumi code is being watched, not the code of the lambda functions.
- I have also tried running `pulumi up` every time a change was made on the lambda code, but that has extreme bad performance and possibly other side effects.

What should I be looking at?

Are there workarounds I could be trying?

Comment: I have also posted this as a [discussion in Pulumi's repository](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi/discussions/11065) and as a [question in their slack channel](https://pulumi-community.slack.com/archives/C84L4E3N1/p1666088263479549). No reactions on any of them so far.

Comment: Depending on your language - https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambda-local, or equivalent may be a better/simpler solution

Comment: I gave up on Pulumi...